# Getting a -1 in the right position with the sum symbol in an equation

Tags: equations

I’m trying to write the following equation (no bold text):

[image]

I'm using the following code:

```
\[ \delta = [(X_i - X_j)^{'} \sum^{-1} {(X_i - X_j)]^\frac{1}{2}} \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(9)  \]
```

But how can I get the -1 in the right position with the sum symbol?

Comment: `\textstyle\sum` instead of just `\sum` might be what you're after.

Comment: @frabjous that would make the rest of the expression text style (but as Mico points out under my answer, this is a Sigma not a summation)

Comment: Unrelated, but instead of `\[...\;(9)\]`, put the expression in an `{equation}` environment, and adjust the equation counter if necessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

You can use `\sum\nolimits^{-1}` on a summation to get the -1 in the superscript position, but here it seems that this is a capital Sigma, in which case the superscript position is the default.

Also use `^{\frac{1}{2}}`, not `\^\frac{1}{2}`. Also always use `'`, not `^{'}` or it will be raised twice.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
 \delta = [(X_i - X_j)' \Sigma^{-1} {(X_i - X_j)]^{\frac{1}{2}}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `textstyle` to place the superscript in the desired position:

[image]

```
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \delta = [(X_i - X_j)' {\textstyle\Sigma^{-1}} {(X_i - X_j)]^{\frac{1}{2}}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, if you just want the Greek letter Sigma, you can use `\Sigma` instead of `\sum`.

[image]

`\delta = [(X_i - X_j)'\Sigma^{-1} {(X_i - X_j)]^{\frac{1}{2}}}`

Comment: `\textstyle` affects the whole equation not just the summation (and doesn't take an argument so the `{}` would generate a mathord box around that subterm.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Ack! I hate when I do that. Fixing now...